# JSTL with fn functions

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a project based in Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8.

in my JSP

```
${fn:toUpperCase(<fmt:message key="${description.language.label}" />)}
```

but I got this error

```
weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: deviceInfo.jsp:118:61: Syntax error in expression. Encountered "<". Expected one of : <INTEGER_LITERAL>, <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL>, <STRING_LITERAL>, "true", "false", "null", "(", ")", "!", "not", "empty", "-", <IDENTIFIER>,
${fn:toUpperCase(<fmt:message key="${description.language.label}" />)}
^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<fmt:message>` tag inside a `${ }` expression doesn't work. You can set a temporary variable to contain the message output and use that inside the expression:

```
<c:set var="msg">
  <fmt:message key="${description.language.label}" />
</c:set>

...

${fn:toUpperCase(msg)}
```